# Is there any way gravity can reflect light?

Tags: gravity, visible-light, reflection

I know gravity leads to certain interesting optical phenomenon. I know light curves around a massive body, I know light red shifts if we look far enough in space. Is there any configuration that could lead to gravity reflecting light?

Answer (score 2):

Taking reflection by the normal meaning, i.e. light hitting a surface and bouncing directly off of, no.

It might be possible given enough super-massive objects (like black holes) configured in the right pattern to achieve **simulated reflection** but that is not **real reflection**, although I suppose at this level it becomes a semantic argument about the meaning of "reflection." Gravity would cause light to come back to the same point in space, but I would have a very hard time thinking of that as a "reflection".

The only way around this I could imagine (being extremely speculative and ridiculous, as in, way beyond Star Trek ridiculous), would be a technology that could create a localized distortion of space-time (a warp field if you will) that could completely redirect light. The amount of energy required to warp space in that way is so ridiculously, insanely off the chart that I can't consider it remotely "possible" -- even if [warping space itself to some degree might be possible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warp-field_experiments). You certainly wouldn't want to touch such a mirror, as it would reflect you also :/ That would hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, very nearly so, although you might argue in an only theoretically relevant fashion. As gravitational lensing is increased by adding mass, beyond just focussing, light can be bent around an object (with the limit of 180 degree bending around a single point-like or spherical object existing only as theoretical limit as light then would become trapped on the event horizon of a black hole with no way to get into or out of that orbit). Essentially this effect, looking far past and around what you would naively expect to be the horizon, has been realistically rendered both by scientists and by Hollywood, and reported on for example by [wired](http://www.wired.com/2014/10/astrophysics-interstellar-black-hole/).

I would call this effect reflection because it is sending light back. If you very narrowly think of reflection as what happens at a single flat mirror surface, you will probably not be content with that answer. However, consider that e.g. a retroreflector also acts much in this way, sending light approximately back where it came from but shifted parallel to the incident beam.

Comment: A light ray that's deflected through 180° by a BH doesn't get trapped on the event horizon, although it does get close to the photon sphere. In units where the event horizon radius, (aka the Schwarzschild radius) is 1, the photon sphere has a radius of 1.5. A 180° deflection trajectory has impact parameter ~2.67848 and closest approach ~1.76031.

Answer (score 1):

You can reflect light using black holes. The reason is that as the light trajectory approaches the photon sphere (the distance from the centre where light can just orbit indefinitely around the hole) it is deflected more and more. Eventually it gets deflected by 180 degrees and comes back in the same direction it arrived.

In Newtonian gravity the sharpest possible deflection of a particle scattering off a mass is 180 degrees; in general relativity any angle is possible, including 360+ degree trajectories that loop several times around the photon sphere before escaping. [These produce successive reflections each a factor $e^{2\pi}$ closer to the optical edge of the hole than the previous one](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-93595-w).

This process distorts the image rather badly, so it is not so much a mirror as a (tiny) reflector. [There has been a paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.03423) analysing how to use this as a spacecraft drive by sending a laser towards a suitable black hole and then reflecting back the incoming photons, but it is rather far away from present feasibility.